# How prove the finite induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, induction

**Theorem** (Finite induction)

Let be **P**$(x)$ a property. So we suppose that

1. **P**$(0)$,
2. **P**$(n)\rightarrow$**P**$\big(S(n)\big)$, for all $n<k$

So **P(n)** is true for all $n<k$.

Unfortunately I can't **formally** prove the theorem. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Consider $\{n\in\Bbb N:\mathbf{P}(n)\text{ or }k\le n\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi:=\{h\in k:\mathbf{P}(h)\}$. So if it was $k\setminus \pi\neq\varnothing$ then there exist $m:=\min{k\setminus \pi}$ so we analise the case where $m=0$ and the case where $m\neq 0$. So for the hypothesis 1 it is impossible that $m=0$. Finally if $m\neq 0$ then $m=S(l)$ for some $l\in k$ and then $l\in\pi$ so that $\mathbf{P}(l)$ is true and so $\mathbf{P}(m)$ is true and this would be impossible.

Comment: Almost: either $m=S(\ell)$ for some $\ell\in k$ (and you do need to mention that $\ell$ is in $k$, not just in $\Bbb N$, or $m=0$. The $m=0$ case is trivial but does have to be mentioned.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I edited the answer. Now is it correct?

Comment: You still haven’t dealt with the possibility that $m=0$. It’s not true that $m=S(\ell)$ for some $\ell\in k$: what’s true is that **either** $m=S(\ell)$ for some $\ell\in k$, **or** $m=0$. (Of course both turn out to be impossible, but for different reasons.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If for hypothesis $\mathbf{P}(0)$ is true then it seems to me that it is impossible that $m=0$, is this uncorrect?

Comment: But you have to **say** so. All you know about $m$ is that it is $\min k\setminus\pi$. That means that $m\in k$, but it does **not** immediately imply that $m\ne 0$; it says only that **either** $m=0$, **or** $m=S(\ell)$ for some $\ell\in k$. The first of these is impossible by clause (1) of the theorem, and the second is impossible by clause (2) — and both cases have to be ruled out.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, I edited the ansewer. Now is it correct?

Comment: Yep, much better; upvoted.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, thanks too much for your assistance!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi professor Scott, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734631/how-prove-the-general-recursion-theorem)? Excuse me for the bother.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Consider the set $S=\lbrace n\in \bigl[\mkern-4mu\bigl|0,k\bigr|\mkern-4.25mu\bigr]\mid \ P(n)\text{ false }\rbrace$ and suppose  $S\ne\varnothing$. As any nonempty subset of $\mathbf N$, it has a least element. Can you deduce a contradiction?

Comment: Let $\pi:=\{n\in\Bbb{N}:\mathbf{P}(n)\}$. So if it was $n\setminus \pi\neq\varnothing$ then there exist $m:=\min{n\setminus \pi}$ and so if $l\in\Bbb{N}$ is such that $m=S(l)$ then $l\in\pi$ and so $\mathbf{P}(l)$ is true and so $\mathbf{P}(m)$ is true and this would be impossible. Do you what say this?

Comment: It's fine (I'd prefer a Π rather than a π). Τ To be quite complete, you have to mention that $m>0$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: No, this doesn’t work: $\mathbf{P}(\ell)$ does not imply $\mathbf{P}(m)$ if $\ell\ge k$. Replace $\mathbf{P}(n)$ with the property $\mathbf{Q}(n)$ that is ‘$\mathbf{P}(n)$ or $k\le n$ and prove that $\mathbf{Q}(n)\to\mathbf{Q}(S(n))$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Excuse me. I had do a terrible mistake: I wanted write $\pi:=\{n\in k:\mathbf{P}(n)\}$.

Comment: Oh! yes. That's how I interpreted  your way of writing.