# If for any $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0)$ whether $x_n\rightarrow x_0$ then $f$ could't be continuous

Tags: general-topology

> **Theorem**
>
> A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ if and only if any net $x_\lambda$ converging to $x_0$ is such that $f(x_\lambda)$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

Clearly any sequence is a net so that by last theorem I argue that a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ if and only if any sequence $x_n$ converging to $x_0$ is such that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$ anway my text says that this is true only for first contable space so that I argue that notwithstanding $x_n\rightarrow x$ imply that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ it could be that there exist a net $x_\lambda$ from a dire
cted set $\Lambda$ different to $\Bbb{N}$ such that $x_\lambda\rightarrow x_0$ but $f(x_\lambda)\nrightarrow f(x_0)$? So could someone explain better this point with a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if a space isn’t first countable, its topology may not be completely determined by its convergent sequences. Here’s a relatively straightforward example.

Let $\tau$ be the order topology on $\omega_1+1$, and let

$$\tau'=\big\{\{\alpha\}:\alpha\in\omega_1\big\}\cup\big\{\{\omega_1\}\cup(\omega_1\setminus C):C\subseteq\omega_1\text{ and }|C|\le\omega\big\}\cup\{\varnothing\}\;;$$

$\tau'$ is a topology on $\omega_1$ finer than $\tau$. (In other words, we just isolate each $\alpha\in\omega_1$ and let the point $\omega_1$ keep its usual nbhds.) Let $X$ be $\langle\omega_1+1,\tau'\rangle$ and $Y$ be $\langle\omega_1+1,\tau\rangle$.

Note that the only convergent sequences in $X$ are the ones that are eventually constant, so **any** function from $X$ to $Y$ takes convergent sequences in $X$ to convergent sequences in $Y$; it will not be surprising, then, that some of those functions are not continuous. Now let

$$f:X\to Y:\alpha\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }\alpha<\omega_1\\
\omega_1,&\text{otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$

then $Y\setminus\{0\}$ is open in $Y$, but its inverse image under $f$ is $\{\omega_1\}$, which is not open in $X$, so $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: It seems to me that $\tau'$ is the discrete topology because if $\{\{\alpha\}:\alpha\in\omega_1\}\subseteq\tau'$ then any subset of $\omega_1$ is open, where is my mistake?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You forgot the **point** $\omega_1$: its nbhds are cocountable sets containing it. The **other** points of $X$ are indeed isolated.

Comment: Okay, I roughly realise. However I don't understand why the only convergent sequences in $X$ are the ones that are eventually constant: indeed if $\alpha_n$ is a sequence in $X$ that converges to $\alpha$ then if $\alpha<\omega_1$ there must exist $n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\alpha_n\in\{\alpha\}$ for any $n\ge n_0$ so that $\alpha$ it looks to me **semi**constant but not always constat and then what happens if $\alpha_n$ converges to $\omega_1$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: *Eventually constant* means that there is an $n_0\in\omega$ such that $\alpha_n=\alpha_{n_0}$ for all $n\ge n_0$; in other words, the sequence is constant from some point on. And the only sequences that converge to $\omega_1$ are constant at $\omega_1$ from some point on.

Comment: Okay, so your *eventually constant* is the same that my *semiconstat*. However is $\alpha_n$ converges to $\omega_1$ then for any countable (eventually infinite) subset $C$ of $\omega_1$ there exist $n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\alpha_n\in\{\omega\}\cup(\omega_1\setminus C)$ so how can I argue that $\alpha_n=\omega_1$ for any $n\ge n_0$? Fogive my confusion.

Comment: Perhaps I understood.

Comment: So if we consider the neighborhoods $\{\omega_1\}\cup\omega$ and $\{\omega_1\}\cup(\omega_1\setminus\omega)$ of $\omega_1$ and if $\alpha_n\neq\omega_1$ for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$ but $\alpha_n$ converges to $\omega_1$ then there exist $n_0,n'_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\alpha_n\in\omega$ for any $n\ge n_0$ and $\alpha_n\in\omega_1\setminus\omega$ for any $n\ge n'_0$ and so $\alpha_n\in(\omega_1\setminus\omega)\cap\omega$ for any $n\ge\max\{n_0,n'_0\}$ and this clearly is impossible so that there exist $n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\alpha_n=\omega_1$ for any $n\ge n_0$, is my a good explanation?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: If $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ converges to $\omega_1$, let $M=\{n\in\omega:\alpha_n\ne\omega_1\}$, and let $C=\{\alpha_n:n\in M\}$. Then $C$ is countable, so $\{\omega_1\}\cup(\omega\setminus C)$ is an open nbhd of $\omega_1$, so there must be an $n_0\in\omega$ such that $\alpha_n=\omega_1\}$ whenever $n_0\le n\in\omega$. Thus, the sequence must be eventually constant at $\omega_1$.

Comment: Okay, now it is all clear. Thanks too much for your assistance!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re welcome!

Comment: Hi professor, perhaps I have found an answer to a my question whose nobody answered: could I ask to you if my answer is correct? Click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739354/if-x-and-y-are-first-countable-then-lim-x-rightarrow-x-0fx-y-0-iff) to see it. Excuse me for the bother.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Yes, it’s okay, though I did fix one significant typo early in the proof. I’d prove it differently, without nets, in a way that I think is easier, but what you’ve done works.

Comment: Okay, I'm happy the proof is correct. Anyway if you say you don't use the nets to prove the theorem then I suppose that you define the limit of a function through the filters, right? After all any net determines a filter which converge iff the net converges and limit point is the same for both.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: No, it can be done just using nbhds.

Comment: Interesting, so how do you proceed?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Let $\hat f(x_0)=y_0$ and $\hat f(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in X\setminus\{x_0\}$. Say that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=y_0$ iff $\hat f$ is continuous at $x_0$, meaning that for each open nbhd $U$ of $y_0$ there is an open nbhd $V$ of $x_0$ such that $\hat f[V]\subseteq U$. It’s easy to show that if this is true, and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\to x_0$ (where $x_n\ne x_0$ for $n\ge 1$), then $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\to y_0$. ...

Comment: ... If it’s not true, $y_0$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that no open nbhd is mapped into it by $\hat f$, so you can take a countable base at $x_0$ and construct a sequence in $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ converging to $x_0$ whose image doesn’t converge to $y_0$.

Comment: I agree with you your way is more simple. Anyway thanks too much for your assistance! You are very courteous with me!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re welcome!